# How to generate a download link for a file stored in the flask server rather than directly downloading the file?

Tags: python, flask

I have built a flask app wherein the user uploads a file, it gets processed and thereafter, gets stored in a particular folder on the flask server itself. Now, I wanted to generate a download link for this file (a link I would be emailing to the user) instead of directly allowing the user to download the file. Any ideas how I should go about it? Thank You.

Answer (score 0):

You can use the following:

*Note: Its recommended to use [send_from_directory](https://flask.palletsprojects.com/en/2.0.x/api/#flask.send_from_directory) and keep the downloadable files in some specific directories `permitted_directory` so that the user can't download any file he wants from the whole server.*

```py
@app.route('/download_link/<path:filename>', methods=['GET', 'POST'])
def download_link():
   permitted_directory='/path/to/directoy/'
   return send_from_directory(directory=permitted_directory, filename=filename,as_attachment=True,cache_timeout=0)
```

then by using the `serverURL/download_link/<filename>`, the file will then be downloaded.

E.g.:

for `serverURL=0.0.0.0:8080` and `file=generated_file.csv`
`0.0.0.0:8080/download_link/generated_file.csv` --> will be the download link for the file

---

You can use `send_file` as an alternative if you are not considering safe approaches and `os.path.isfile()` for handling unexisting files.

Comment: So when I used send_from_directory, the server if giving an unhandled exception error while when I use send_file, it works fine....any specific reason for it?